# Unable to connect to greenplum postgresql from pgadmin on windows

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I have PGADMIN 3 on my Window system. I am not able to connect to Greenplum-Postgresql which is under Virtualbox-Centos machine. Inside Virtualbox I am able to createdb using psql, but not using pgadmin from windows machine.

Please suggest what should I do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not have the gpadmin database either.  Start with this:

```
psql template1 -c "select * from pg_database where datname = 'gpadmin'"
```

If the database doesn't exist, do this:

```
psql template1 -c "create database gpadmin"
```

Next, execute this to allow external connections that are authenticated with encrypted password:

```
echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" >> $MASTER_DATA_DIRECTORY/pg_hba.conf
psql -c "alter user gpadmin password 'password'"
gpstop -u
```

Back to pgAdmin, connect to your vm (use ifconfig to get the ip address) as user gpadmin, password 'password', and port 5432.

Answer (score 1):

GPDB/Postgresql deny remote access in default. You will need to add ACL to pg_hba.conf in $MASTER_DATA_DIRECTORY, ie, /data/master/gpseg-1/pg_hba.conf.
refer to 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html
or
http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43100/admin_guide/client_auth.html
for details

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you paste exact error.

- Make sure you have added IP in [listen_address](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html) in postgresql.conf (Requires restart)
- Make sure `iptables` and `ip6tables` are not running. Run below commands to check

  - `service iptables status`
  - `service ip6tables status`